# Full join two datasets as rows duplicating the ids below on another

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to join two datasets, with the second datasets ids duplicated under each other.

```
df1 <- structure (list(
  subject_id = c("191-5467", "191-6784", "191-3457", "191-0987", "191-1245", "191-1945"), 
  m_or_c = c("m","m","m","m","m","m"),
  edta_code = c("EDTA45", "EDTA79", "EDTA20", "EDTA66", "EDTA12", "EDTA74"), 
  ipv = c("0", "3", "2", "2", "1", "2")), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

```
df2 <- structure (list(
  subject_id = c("191-5467", "191-6784", "191-3457", "191-0987", "191-1245", "191-1945"), 
m_or_c = c("c","c","c","c","c","c","c"),
  edta_code = c("EDTA49", "EDTA95", "EDTA20", "EDTA68", "EDTA89", "EDTA30"), 
  ipv = c("1", "4", "6", "4", "1", "3")), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

What I've tried

```
df3 <- full_join(df1, df2, by = "subject_id")
```

Output:
This isn't what I need.

| subject_id | m_or_c.x | edta_code.x | ipv.x | m_or_c.y | edta_code.y | ipv.x |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 191-0987 | m | EDTA12 | 1 | c | EDTA89 | 1 |
| 191-1245 | m | EDTA20 | 2 | c | EDTA20 | 6 |
| 191-1945 | m | EDTA45 | 0 | c | EDTA49 | 1 |
| 191-3457 | m | EDTA66 | 2 | c | EDTA68 | 4 |
| 191-5467 | m | EDTA74 | 2 | c | EDTA30 | 3 |
| 191-6784 | m | EDTA79 | 2 | c | EDTA95 | 4 |

Desired table

| subject_id | m_or_c | edta_code | ipv |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 191-0987 | m | EDTA12 | 1 |
| 191-0987 | c | EDTA89 | 1 |
| 191-1245 | m | EDTA20 | 2 |
| 191-1245 | c | EDTA20 | 6 |
| 191-1945 | m | EDTA45 | 0 |
| 191-1945 | c | EDTA49 | 1 |
| 191-3457 | m | EDTA66 | 2 |
| 191-3457 | c | EDTA68 | 4 |
| 191-5467 | m | EDTA74 | 2 |
| 191-5467 | c | EDTA30 | 3 |
| 191-6784 | m | EDTA79 | 2 |
| 191-6784 | c | EDTA95 | 4 |

Please assist

Comment: My mistake. Just added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No join needed I think. All you need is to bind the data.frames together, and set the order to your liking.

**base R**

```
final <- rbind(df1,df2)
final[with(final, order(subject_id, m_or_c)), ]
#    subject_id m_or_c edta_code ipv
# 10   191-0987      c    EDTA68   4
# 4    191-0987      m    EDTA66   2
# 11   191-1245      c    EDTA89   1
# 5    191-1245      m    EDTA12   1
# 12   191-1945      c    EDTA30   3
# 6    191-1945      m    EDTA74   2
# 9    191-3457      c    EDTA20   6
# 3    191-3457      m    EDTA20   2
# 7    191-5467      c    EDTA49   1
# 1    191-5467      m    EDTA45   0
# 8    191-6784      c    EDTA95   4
# 2    191-6784      m    EDTA79   3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bind_rows` from `dplyr` package and order the data frame.

```
df3 = dplyr::bind_rows(df1,df2)
df3 = df3[order(df3$subject_id),]
# subject_id m_or_c edta_code ipv
# 191-0987      m    EDTA66   2
# 191-0987      c    EDTA68   4
# 191-1245      m    EDTA12   1
# 191-1245      c    EDTA89   1
# 191-1945      m    EDTA74   2
# 191-1945      c    EDTA30   3
# 191-3457      m    EDTA20   2
# 191-3457      c    EDTA20   6
# 191-5467      m    EDTA45   0
# 191-5467      c    EDTA49   1
# 191-6784      m    EDTA79   3
# 191-6784      c    EDTA95   4
```